# Check if users are in conversation with $in operator

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

How can i make my code search for two user ids but take in consideration if its more users?

lets say my db only contains a conv with user 10 and 4.

my code:

```
return Conversations.findOne({"users.userid": { $in: SearchUsers }}).then(function (response) {
                return response;
        });
```

Test 1: users with ids: `[10,4]` -> would return the conversation. aka ( `true`)

test 2: users with ids `[10,4,8]` -> This example would **NOT** return it. Even that both 10 and 4 is in the users, cause there is more members in it, and therefore not a private for them alone. , because it does not have an match, even that 10 and 4 is there, there is a user with id 8, and it dosent exist. ( `false` )

The idea is to make like facebook has, group chat system, and in this particular matter, to check if an conversation exists or not.

Ideally the $searchUsers could contain anything from 1-50+ userids, and i need it returned if all the users are in a match, if not all is in it, then it wont return any.

Comment: You may have to use different, or more, operators than `$in`.  As far as I am aware, `$in` will return true so long as the value is any of the values in the array.  So, if you had two search users, so long as one of them is in the conversation, let alone two, it would return the conversation.

Answer (score 2):

tryThe $all operator : it should behave like an $and with $in

```
Conversations.findOne({"users.userid": { $all: SearchUsers }}).then(function (response) {
                return response;
        });
```